# Viewing the ASCII codes of piped-in characters

Tags: bash, unix, gnu

Is there a command that would let me see ASCII values of characters outputted from a program?

Say I pipe in a `NUL` character and a `p`, could I get a `0` and a `112` out?

Comment: Probably `hexdump` or `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `od -t d1` to output the ascii values of a file. When using this, he starts the first column with the offset within the stream (the adress), when you dont need it, you can pipe it into `cut -d \  -f 2-` or similar.